# i want to use a use checkbox for choosing either male or female

Tags: android, android-checkbox

When I use the above code and select `male` checkbox I can only select `male` checkbox. I cannot select `female` if I unchecked `male` checkbox.

```
checkboxmale.setOnCheckedChangeListener (new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() 
{                                                  
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
    if (isChecked) {                                                            
            Toast.makeText(DonorReg.this, "male", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                                                           
            checkboxfemale.setEnabled(false); // disable checkbox
        }
    }
});

checkboxfemale.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, booleanisChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
        Toast.makeText(DonorReg.this, "Female", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        checkboxmale.setEnabled(false); // disable checkbox
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: So you want when you uncheck the male box it will "Automatically" check the female box and otherwise?

Comment: No, you want to use a RadioGroup with two RadioButtons inside. You don't have to set anything and don't risk to check them both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to suggest change it to radio button because at a time user can select only one option and Radio option is good for that.

[image]

layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/genderRadioGroup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/maleRadioButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Male" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/femaleRadioButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Female" />
    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

class file

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        RadioGroup genderRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.genderRadioGroup);
        genderRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                switch (checkedId) {
                    case R.id.maleRadioButton: {

                        break;
                    }
                    case R.id.femaleRadioButton: {

                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add another condition when the checkbox is unchecked.

```
checkboxmale.setOnCheckedChangeListener (new 
              CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() 
{                                                  
  @Override
  public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean 
                                                      isChecked) {
   if (isChecked) {                                                            
         Toast.makeText(DonorReg.this, "male", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                                                           
         checkboxfemale.setEnabled(false); // disable checkbox
   }else{
         Toast.makeText(DonorReg.this, "Unchecked male", 
                                         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         checkboxfemale.setenabled(true);
   }
  }
});
```

Do the same for female checkchange listener.

Answer (score 0):

When you disable a `View` it will never detect any event like Click or Touch unless you Enable it again. So for your case disabling was unnecessary just uncheck the Checkboxes programmatically.

So go change this line:

```
checkboxfemale.setEnabled(false);
```

**To this:**

```
checkboxfemale.setChecked(false);
```

Also change this line:

```
checkboxmale.setEnabled(false);
```

**To this:**

```
checkboxmale.setChecked(false);
```

From there your code will work as expected.